# error parsing staging-ingress.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 5: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: azure, yaml, namespaces, azure-aks

I request your support, can you help me with the reason why when I run the following script on my Azure AKS, the following error appears?

"error parsing staging-ingress.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 5: mapping values are not allowed in this context"

Currently the version of my Azure AKS is version 1.27 and the version of the nginx Ingress Controller is 1.8.3.

Here is the script I'm running
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: staging-ingress
namespace: stage
spec:
rules:
-host: qa.test.net
http:
paths:
- path: /staging
pathType: Prefix
backend:
service:
name: staging-service
port:
number: 80

this the namespaces that I configured
adminseguros@AVMSEGURODEVQA:~$ kubectl get ns -A
NAME                STATUS   AGE
aks-command         Active   21d
default             Active   21d
development         Active   12d
gatekeeper-system   Active   21d
ingress-basic       Active   12d
kube-node-lease     Active   21d
kube-public         Active   21d
kube-system         Active   21d
stage               Active   11d

I trying to install the old script on the nacespaces called stage

adminseguros@AVMSEGURODEVQA:~$ kubectl apply -f staging-ingress.yaml -n stage
and after apper this messages

adminseguros@AVMSEGURODEVQA:~$ kubectl apply -f staging-ingress.yaml -n stage
error: error parsing staging-ingress.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 5: mapping values are not allowed in this context
adminseguros@AVMSEGURODEVQA:~$

Please help me !!!

I have created the yaml files according to Microsoft documentation and parsing errors appear.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering typically arises from a syntax issue in your YAML file. YAML is quite strict about indentation and structure, and even small mistakes can lead to parsing errors. Let's correct the provided Ingress YAML definition based on your description.

Here is the script content you provided, reformatted for clarity and correctness:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: staging-ingress
  namespace: stage
spec:
  rules:
  - host: qa.test.net
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /staging
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: staging-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Apply it using

```
kubectl apply -f staging-ingress.yaml -n stage
```

[image]

Actually, YAML relies heavily on indentation to define structure. So, I added a space before `host` to correctly format it as a list item under `rules` and fixed the indentation for each level within `spec`, `rules`, `http`, `paths`, and `backend` sections . By the way you can use online YAML validators or command-line tools like `yamllint` for this purpose. Makes it easier.